# Add key word values to next lines until it finds the next key word - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say, I have a list of values like this,

```
["Started with no key words",
PCC WITH NOTHING,
ABB,CAI null V00011 11/06/18,
ANDERS,SAND null V000103 07/10/17,
"",
PSP SECONDARY,
MUNCH,TORY null V000113 04/08/19 ,
"There is no key words here",
PCC WITH SOEMTHING,
BEC,RUMA null V00011 04/17/19 ,
"There is no keyword here too",
ASP HAS IT,
XON,ANDREA null V00011 03/27/19]
```

I have a key word list like this:

```
key_word_list = ['PCC', 'PSP', 'ASP']
```

Now as I go through each key word from `key_word_list`, if key word found add those values records after that line where key word found until the next keyword. An output like this,

```
["Started with no key words",
PCC WITH NOTHING,
PCC ABB,CAI null V00011 11/06/18,
PCC ANDERS,SAND null V000103 07/10/17,
"",
PSP SECONDARY,
PSP MUNCH,TORY null V000113 04/08/19 ,
"There is no key words here",
PCC WITH SOEMTHING,
PCC BEC,RUMA null V00011 04/17/19 ,
"There is no keyword here too",
ASP HAS IT,
ASP XON,ANDREA null V00011 03/27/19]
```

How can I do this in python? Is it doable? what will be the best way to do?
I started with something like this,

```
for ind, j in enumerate(key_word_list):
    # intermediate_index = []  # Was thinking to save index, but no idea what to do with this either to proceed to next line until next key word
    for index,i in enumerate(biglist):
        stripped_line = i.strip()
        if j in stripped_line:
            #do something not sure how to check until next keyword
```

Comment: To check if the line starts with the string, you can use [str.startswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Comment: @MichaelKolber Agreed, but not sure how to keep adding the key word until the next key word. If you notice, keywords repeat in later sentences.

Comment: Can you provide your desired output for your example inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a generator function that will keep track of the current keyword and yield lines as it goes through:

```
def append_keys(l, kw):
    current_kw = None

    for line in l:
         # deal with initial lines with no kw
        if current_kw is None and not any(line.startswith(k) for k in kw):
            yield line
            continue
        try:
            k = next(k for k in kw if line.startswith(k))
            current_kw = k
            yield line
        except StopIteration:
            yield current_kw + " " + line

new_list = list(append_keys(biglist, key_word_list))
```

**new_list:**

```
['PCC WITH NOTHING',
 'PCC ABB,CAI null V00011 11/06/18',
 'PCC ANDERS,SAND null V000103 07/10/17',
 'PSP SECONDARY',
 'PSP MUNCH,TORY null V000113 04/08/19',
 'PCC WITH SOEMTHING',
 'PCC BEC,RUMA null V00011 04/17/19',
 'ASP HAS IT',
 'ASP XON,ANDREA null V00011 03/27/19']
```

Being a generator means you can loop over the list one at a time without creating another list in memory if you want — which is nice if the list is really big.

Comment: Superb! Works great. Did not know anything about generators before!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
d = ['PCC WITH NOTHING', 'ABB,CAI null V00011 11/06/18', 'ANDERS,SAND null V000103 07/10/17', 'PSP SECONDARY', 'MUNCH,TORY null V000113 04/08/19', 'PCC WITH SOEMTHING', 'BEC,RUMA null V00011 04/17/19', 'ASP HAS IT', 'XON,ANDREA null V00011 03/27/19']
l = ['PCC', 'PSP', 'ASP']
```

---

```
new_d = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in groupby(d, key=lambda x:any(x.startswith(i) for i in l))]
_d = [[b[0], [i for i in l if b[0].startswith(i)][0]] if a else b for a, b in new_d]
final_result = [[_d[i][0], *[f'{_d[i][-1]} {j}' for j in _d[i+1]]] for i in range(0, len(_d), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[['PCC WITH NOTHING', 'PCC ABB,CAI null V00011 11/06/18', 'PCC ANDERS,SAND null V000103 07/10/17'], 
 ['PSP SECONDARY', 'PSP MUNCH,TORY null V000113 04/08/19'], 
 ['PCC WITH SOEMTHING', 'PCC BEC,RUMA null V00011 04/17/19'], 
 ['ASP HAS IT', 'ASP XON,ANDREA null V00011 03/27/19']]
```

Comment: thank you :) but looks a bit difficult to read an understand :(